# Fetch all the timestamp values from the end of a line in a file and do the Total and Average operations on them

Tags: python

I have a log file pattern that below code generates.

```
2019-01-30 08:34:46.463 -0800 INFO [626] - Program Ended: xxxx::xxxxxxx::xxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [linear_national] pid 626 user dexter after 00:26:15

2019-01-30 08:37:04.207 -0800 INFO [8749] - Program Ended: xxxxx::xxxxxx::xxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] pid 8749 user dexter after 00:01:33

2019-01-30 08:39:55.117 -0800 INFO [31467] - Program Ended: xxx::xxxxxx::xxxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [linear_national] pid 31467 user dexter after 00:02:20

2019-01-30 08:45:09.752 -0800 INFO [32104] - Program Ended: RTK::xxxxxxx::xxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] pid 32104 user dexter after 00:04:33

2019-01-30 08:46:20.511 -0800 INFO [15031] - Program Ended: xxx::xxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] pid 15031 user dexter after 00:00:45

2019-01-30 08:48:08.232 -0800 INFO [15224] - Program Ended: RTK::xxxxxxx::xxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxx] [linear_national] pid 15224 user dexter after 00:01:33

2019-01-30 08:50:52.541 -0800 INFO [15539] - Program Ended: RTK::xxxxxx::xxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [linear_national] pid 15539 user dexter after 00:02:16

2019-01-30 08:58:05.386 -0800 INFO [16168] - Program Ended: xxx:xxxxx::xxxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [linear_national] pid 16168 user dexter after 00:06:29

2019-01-30 09:06:52.701 -0800 INFO [20374] - Program Ended: xxx::xxxxxx::xxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for exports [xxxxxxxxxxxx] [xxxxxxxxx] pid 20374 user dexter after 00:08:16
```

I want to fetch all the time stamp values from each line and then take out the total and average of this using the same code below i.e have to do something extra with the pattern.

what pattern should i use to parse the file in such way and also how do i calculate the whole thing?

```
src_dict = ("/xxx/home/dexter/work/xxxxx/xxxxx/logs")
pattern = re.compile ('(.*)for exports(.*)')

for passed_files in os.listdir(src_dict):
    files = os.path.join(src_dict, passed_files)
    strng = open(files)
    for lines in strng.readlines():
        if re.search(pattern, lines):
            print lines
```

Comment: Please be more clear. E.g. total and average of what exactly?

Comment: Sorry Total and Average time to be more specific..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to just split and take the last part of each line (which contains the duration you are after, I think).

Incorporated in the script that you already have:

```
import datetime

dir_path = "/xxx/home/dexter/work/xxxxx/xxxxx/logs"
pattern = re.compile ('(.*)for exports(.*)')
n = 0
sum_seconds = 0

for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    with open(os.path.join(dir_path, filename)) as f:
        for line in file:
            if re.search(pattern, line):
                print(line)

                # remove newline at end, split by spaces
                parts = line.strip().split()
                if len(parts) > 0:
                    n += 1

                # this should be a string in the format 'hh:mm:ss'
                duration_str = parts[-1]
                print(duration_str)
                h, m, s = duration_str.split(':')
                sum_seconds += (int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s))

print('Total (in seconds):', sum_seconds)
print('Total (formated as hh:mm:ss):', str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=sum_seconds)))
if n > 0:
    avg_seconds = round(sum_seconds / n)
    print('Avg (in seconds):', avg_seconds)
    print('Avg (formated as hh:mm:ss):', str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=avg_seconds)))
```

---

You could also parse the duration string and create `datetime.timedelta` objects, but I think that would not be necessary for this simple case.

Comment: ok so i redirect the output from my above code to a file and then write a separate snippet that you suggested?? Any suggestions on how can i combine both the codes so i don't have to execute both the python files separately.....sorry for all this but i am a beginner to python scripting have done the same in shell but wanted to know how this works.

Comment: h, m, s = parts[-1].split(':')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1).......it gives me this error when i try to pass the same file to it

Comment: I edited my answer. Consider using `with ... as` to open files (you forgot to close the files in your code), and use `for line in f` instead of `.readlines()`. You can google why that is advisable.

Comment: @MfjoneZ I also added `print()` before where you say you get an error. See the output you get with that to determine the source of the error when trying to split by `:`.

Comment: ok it's working.  gives me ('total:', 3240)
('avg:', 360) ...ok can the output be split using ':' i mean 32:40 like that....

Comment: @MfjoneZ Is that last part ("can the output be split like that") a question? If it is, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: yes like the output now is ('total:', 3240) ('avg:', 360) so i just want it like 32:40 and 3:60 i mean i should come to know like hours minutes seconds....hope you get me?

Comment: @MfjoneZ I added pretty printing to my answer; I used `datetime.timedelta` for that

Comment: it prints ('Total (in seconds):', 3240)
('Total (formated as hh:mm:ss):', datetime.timedelta(0, 3240))
('Avg (in seconds):', 360.0)
('Avg (formated as hh:mm:ss):', datetime.timedelta(0, 360))....

Comment: Then cast to `str` before printing. I edited my answer to use `str(...timedelta...)`.

Comment: Great thanks a lot man.....just one question can you suggest some good site to practice and learn python scripting i am a beginner and want to learn with hands on some practice....again thanks a lot.